# OpenGL flickering screen

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graphics, 3d

I've written a simple opengl running in my ubuntu laptop. It is a small solar system including the sun and the earth, the earth rotates around the sun. The problem with my program is the screen keep blinking continuously every time I try to run it.

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#define SUN_RADIUS 0.4
#define EARTH_RADIUS 0.06
#define MOON_RADIUS 0.016

GLfloat EARTH_ORBIT_RADIUS = 0.9;
GLfloat year = 0.0;

void init() {
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClearDepth(10.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}


void renderScene() {
    gluLookAt(
        0.0, 0.0, -4.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0
    );
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.7);
    glutWireSphere(SUN_RADIUS, 50, 50);
    glPushMatrix();

    glRotatef(year, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glTranslatef(EARTH_ORBIT_RADIUS, 0.0, 0.0);

    glColor3f(0.0, 0.7, 1.0);
    glutWireSphere(EARTH_RADIUS, 10, 10);

    glPopMatrix();
}

void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    renderScene();
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void idle() {
    year += 0.2;
    display();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("Solar System");

    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: You aren't clearing the depth buffer. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I add **glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);** to my code but the problem still remains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `gluLookAt()` multiplies by the current matrix, it does not load a new one.  Multiple `gluLookAt()`s multiplied together aren't very meaningful.
- Reload proj/modelview matrices each frame, helps prevent matrix oddities.
- Let GLUT do it's job, don't call `display()` from `idle()`, use `glutPostRedisplay()` instead.  That way GLUT knows to call `display()` the next time through the event loop.

All together:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

#define SUN_RADIUS 0.4
#define EARTH_RADIUS 0.06
#define MOON_RADIUS 0.016

GLfloat EARTH_ORBIT_RADIUS = 0.9;
GLfloat year = 0.0;

void renderScene()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( -1, 1, -1, 1, -100, 100 );

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt
        (
        0.0, 0.0, -4.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0
        );

    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.7);
    glutWireSphere(SUN_RADIUS, 50, 50);

    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(year, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glTranslatef(EARTH_ORBIT_RADIUS, 0.0, 0.0);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.7, 1.0);
    glutWireSphere(EARTH_RADIUS, 10, 10);
    glPopMatrix();
}

void display()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClearDepth(10.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    renderScene();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void idle()
{
    year += 0.2;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("Solar System");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc( idle );

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem. So, is is true that multiplying many gluLookAt matrices will cause blinking issues?

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to tearing if you aren't doing any kind of v-sync (Which it doesn't look like your code is).  Try adding a sleep time to your display method (like sleep(500)).  This isn't the correct way to fix this, but this will allow you to verify that it is the issue.  If it is, look into adding v-sync to your application.

Comment: I have problem with tearing on ubuntu, it was caused by  compositing manager.

Comment: It seems to be that sleep() is a Windows function, is there any similar function in Ubuntu Linux?

Comment: It should be there.  I think you need to include unistd.h and call it from there.  pthread.h might also have it as well (really depends on what libraries are included).

One solution I'm seeing is at the bottom of this thread as well for a custom sleep function: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=296142

Comment: I've added sleep() function as you suggested. However, the program does not draw anything and stuck at runtime.

Comment: Try it with a value of 50.  If you added that method, make sure it works, as I am not sure if that one is properly made.

Basically, you want to slow down how quickly your display method runs.  That sleep method may be never ending, or take too long.